# ECFP harder than ECDLP?

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm

Given two points $P$ and $Q = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i.P$ over $E_p(a, b)$ for $x_1,x_2,...,x_n \in \mathbb F_p$. The Elliptic Curve Factorization Problem (ECFP) is to find the points $x_1.P,x_2.P,...,x_n.P$

Is ECFP harder than ECDLP ? Can anyone provide me the proof ?

Answer (score 3):

It's not harder.

- Solve the DL problem to get $x$ in $Q=x.P$.
- $Q = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i.P = (\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i).P= x.P$

=> any set of $x_i$ that sums to $x$ (modulo the group order) is a solution to ECFP.

Comment: The question would be rather how it is used and whether you have the correct set of $x_i$ values. I see this similar to how Shamir's Secret Sharing is information-theoretically perfectly secure.

Comment: @CodesInChaos how will you find the correct set of $x_i$ values ? You will find $x$ by DL problem and then break $x$ into set of $x_i$. So don't you think it is harder than ECDLP ?

Comment: @Sandy What do you mean by "*the* correct set"?

Comment: @CodesInChaos suppose $x_1 = 2$ and $x_2 = 8$ then $x = 10$. So you have $P$ and $Q = 10.P$. By DL problem we can get back $x = 10$. But how to find $x_1$ and $x_2$ ?

Comment: @Sandy It's an [Underdetermined system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system) of linear equations. There are many equally valid valid solutions with nothing to distinguish one of them as the single correct one. But that doesn't make it a harder problem in the cryptographic sense.

Comment: @CodesInChaos So isn't it similar to the [Subset Sum Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) ? Given $x$ and $p$ integers, we need to find the subset $x_1,x_2,...x_n$ from $(0,p-1)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = x$